# Raspberry Pi (SSH X11 Forwarding) Desktop Display on MAC Strange Behavior

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, x11

I'm trying to get the desktop of my Raspberry Pi to display on my mac. I've done this numerous times before with an X11 display app installed locally on the mac ( in this case XQuartz ) and X11 forwarding enabeled on the raspberry pi, through SSH with X11 enabled.

Here are the commands:

```
bryans-mbp:~ bryan$ ssh -X pi@192.168.1.185
pi@192.168.1.185's password:
```

With XQuartz running

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lxsession&

[1] 2515
```

Heres the strange thing, XQuartz brings up a window in the background, it replaces the background for my desktop however its just the raspberry pi logo (same logo on the raspi desktop). I can't minimize or make use of the window. So, it's displaying something. But I can't use or interact with the display.

What am I doing wrong?

Please see the attached link (cant post images due to experience).

[RPI DESKTOP SCREEN GRAB](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/14GWo1btXDGzIQZBocXvMPzcLi7IJ65QAyV31Qfk549w/pub?w=1440&h=1080)

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed weird, but if you want to see the whole desktop rather than run individual X apps, what I'd instead suggest is installing `xrdp` on the Pi, with `sudo apt-get install xrdp`.

Then you can use an RDP client (e.g. [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12&ls=1) or its [older non-App Store version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18140)) to connect. It performs significantly better than X, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went with VNC which meets my requirements. I'll try out xrdp. Still confused as to why the desktop is a problem. I was able to launch other apps from the PI w/o issues. Just not the full desktop. Strange strange strange.

Answer (score 0):

the right command for quartz x11 users is:

/etc/X11/Xsession

instead of

lxsession&